# Sitecore 9.0.1 installation is failing with Solr 6.6.3

Tags: solr, sitecore-install-framework, powershell

I already have 2 instances running on my machine with Solr version 6.6.2 for POC purpose I am installing Sitecore 9.0.1 instance with Solr version 6.6.3.Solr is installed using the powershell script but while running the sitecore script i am getting the error saying that "Unable to connect to remote server".But the solr is up and running on the web page.
[image]

**Xconnect-solr log file**

```
**********************
PSVersion: 5.1.18362.1171
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.18362.1171
BuildVersion: 10.0.18362.1171
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is C:\Windows\system32\xconnect-solr.210409 (10).log
                                                 ************************************
                                                      Sitecore Install Framework
                                                           Version - 1.2.1
                                                 ************************************


WorkingDirectory  : C:\Windows\system32
LogPath           : C:\Windows\system32\xconnect-solr.210409 (10).log
WhatIf            : False
Verbose           : SilentlyContinue

Debug             : SilentlyContinue
WarningAction     : Continue
ErrorAction       : Stop
InformationAction : Continue




[------------------------------------------------------- StopSolr : ManageService --------------------------------------------------]
[StopSolr]:[Updating] Solr-6.6.3
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Solr-6.6.3 (solr-6.6.3)' to stop...

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  solr-6.6.3         Solr-6.6.3



[----------------------------------------------------- CleanCores : EnsurePath -----------------------------------------------------]
[CleanCores]:[Clean] C:\SOLR633\solr\solr-6.6.3\server\solr\sitecore633_xdb
[CleanCores]:[Clean] C:\SOLR633\solr\solr-6.6.3\server\solr\sitecore633_xdb_rebuild
[CleanCores]:[Create] C:\SOLR633\solr\solr-6.6.3\server\solr\sitecore633_xdb
[CleanCores]:[Create] C:\SOLR633\solr\solr-6.6.3\server\solr\sitecore633_xdb_rebuild

[----------------------------------------------- PrepareCores [1] : Copy -----------------------------------------------------------]
[PrepareCores [1]]:[Copying] C:\SOLR633\solr\solr-6.6.3\server\solr\configsets\basic_configs\* => C:\SOLR633\solr\solr-6.6.3\server\solr\sitecore633_xdb

[----------------------------------------------- PrepareCores [2] : Copy -----------------------------------------------------------]
[PrepareCores [2]]:[Copying] C:\SOLR633\solr\solr-6.6.3\server\solr\configsets\basic_configs\* => C:\SOLR633\solr\solr-6.6.3\server\solr\sitecore633_xdb_rebuild

[------------------------------------------------------ StartSolr : ManageService --------------------------------------------------]
[StartSolr]:[Updating] Solr-6.6.3
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Solr-6.6.3 (solr-6.6.3)' to start...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Solr-6.6.3 (solr-6.6.3)' to start...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Solr-6.6.3 (solr-6.6.3)' to start...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Solr-6.6.3 (solr-6.6.3)' to start...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Solr-6.6.3 (solr-6.6.3)' to start...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Solr-6.6.3 (solr-6.6.3)' to start...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Solr-6.6.3 (solr-6.6.3)' to start...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Solr-6.6.3 (solr-6.6.3)' to start...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Solr-6.6.3 (solr-6.6.3)' to start...
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Solr-6.6.3 (solr-6.6.3)' to start...

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  solr-6.6.3         Solr-6.6.3



[------------------------------------------------ CreateCores [1] : ManageSolrCore -------------------------------------------------]
[CreateCores [1]]:[Requesting] https://solr:8986/solr
**********************
Command start time: 20210409132955
**********************
PS>TerminatingError(Invoke-WebRequest): "Unable to connect to the remote server"
WARNING: [1/5] Request Failed: Unable to connect to the remote server
[CreateCores [1]]:[Requesting] https://solr:8986/solr
**********************
Command start time: 20210409132959
**********************
PS>TerminatingError(Invoke-WebRequest): "Unable to connect to the remote server"
WARNING: [2/5] Request Failed: Unable to connect to the remote server
[CreateCores [1]]:[Requesting] https://solr:8986/solr
**********************
Command start time: 20210409133003
**********************
PS>TerminatingError(Invoke-WebRequest): "Unable to connect to the remote server"
WARNING: [3/5] Request Failed: Unable to connect to the remote server
[CreateCores [1]]:[Requesting] https://solr:8986/solr
**********************
Command start time: 20210409133008
**********************
PS>TerminatingError(Invoke-WebRequest): "Unable to connect to the remote server"
WARNING: [4/5] Request Failed: Unable to connect to the remote server
[CreateCores [1]]:[Requesting] https://solr:8986/solr
**********************
Command start time: 20210409133012
**********************
PS>TerminatingError(Invoke-WebRequest): "Unable to connect to the remote server"
WARNING: [5/5] Request Failed: Unable to connect to the remote server
**********************
Command start time: 20210409133012
**********************
PS>TerminatingError(): "Could not complete request for https://solr:8986/solr - Unable to connect to the remote server"
>> TerminatingError(Invoke-ManageSolrCoreTask): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Could not complete request for https://solr:8986/solr - Unable to connect to the remote server"
>> TerminatingError(Invoke-ManageSolrCoreTask): "The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Could not complete request for https://solr:8986/solr - Unable to connect to the remote server"
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Could not complete request for https://solr:8986/solr - Unable to connect to the remote 
server
At D:\backup\Install-Sitecore901.ps1:31 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Could not complete request for https://solr:8986/solr - Unable to connect to the remote server
At D:\backup\Install-Sitecore901.ps1:31 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:01:50
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20210409133049
**********************
```

The script i am following

```
#define parameters
$prefix = "sitecore633"
$PSScriptRoot = “C:\Users\abc\Sitecore9.0.1\Resources663” 
$XConnectCollectionService = "$prefix.xconnect"
$sitecoreSiteName = "$prefix.local"
$SolrUrl = "https://solr:8986/solr"
$SolrRoot = "C:\SOLR633\solr\solr-6.6.3"
$SolrService = "Solr-6.6.3"
$SqlServer = "abc"
$SqlAdminUser = "rtytt"
$SqlAdminPassword = "abc"

#install client certificate for xconnect 
$certParams = 
@{
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-createcert.json"
    CertificateName = "$prefix.xconnect_client"
    RootCertFileName = "SIF121CBMRoot"
}
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @certParams -Verbose

# install solr cores for xdb 
$solrParams = 
@{
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-solr.json"
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl 
    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot 
    SolrService = $SolrService 
    CorePrefix = $prefix
}
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams

# deploy xconnect instance 
$xconnectParams = 
@{
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-xp0.json"
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.1 rev. 171219 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip"
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"
    Sitename = $XConnectCollectionService 
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName 
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix 
    SqlServer = $SqlServer 
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser 
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword 
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix 
    SolrURL = $SolrUrl
}
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams

# install solr cores for sitecore 
$solrParams = 
@{
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-solr.json"
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl 
    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot 
    SolrService = $SolrService 
    CorePrefix = $prefix
}
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams

# install sitecore instance 
$xconnectHostName = "$prefix.xconnect"
$sitecoreParams = 
@{
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-XP0.json"
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.1 rev. 171219 (OnPrem)_single.scwdp.zip"
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix 
    SqlServer = $SqlServer 
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser 
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword 
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl 
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName 
    Sitename = $sitecoreSiteName 
    XConnectCollectionService = "https://$XConnectCollectionService"
}

Install-SitecoreConfiguration @sitecoreParams
```

I am using the existing SIF which I have used for other 2 instances.

Please suggest what am I doing wrong.

Thank you

Comment: The Solr 6.6.2 instance is running on which port?

Comment: one instance on 8983 and another one on 8985.@PeterProchazka

Comment: Can antivirus block this? https://blog.martinmiles.net/post/sitecore-9-installer-unable-to-connect-to-remote-server

Comment: Also based on your screenshot, I would recommend not running ps1 installation scripts from C:\Windows\System32 ....

Comment: Installation scripts are in D drive only the resources are in C drive @PeterProchazka

Comment: https://solr:8986/solr is this working from your browser? Try it with http and https and see if it works

Comment: can you try https://localhost:8986/solr instead of https://solr:8986/solr

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Solr instance start up time is a bit higher than usual.

You should increase PostDelay settings.

Inside of installation package, search for sitecore-solr.json and modify PostDelay setting to 30 seconds:

```
"StartSolr": {
"Description" : "Starts the Solr service.",
            "Type": "ManageService",
            "Params":{
                "Name": "[parameter('SolrService')]",
                "Status": "Running",
                "PostDelay": 30000
            }
        },
```

Comment: No it is still failing @Peter Prochazka